# Detect when a page/element has finished updating javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

To be clear I'm not asking to detect when the page has finished loading but rather when an update to the DOM has been completed.

Consider the case - A website that has a list of options and some questions, answering the questions creates a post request for updated/new information to populate/change this list.
So my question is how do I detect when either the element containing the list or the whole page has finished updating?

The catch:
Need to do it without a mutation observer. This is due to the amount of information changing in the list causing the mutation observer to overload the thread and in turn causing the website to crash.

Comment: You can start here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver When you have a bit of code of your try, and you are stuck with a specific problem, come back to stackoverflow and ask a specific question. This should be closed as too broad.

Comment: And read about how to ask: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask || http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: If you read the question, as I state, I cannot use MuObs and I do fully understand what they do.

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood the `without`, but the essence is the same, this is a question asking for coding, instead of resolve a specific problem. If you read the links i've attached, you will understand how to ask and what is a valid question on stackoverflow.

Comment: Hi, did you end up solving this problem?

Comment: Not really. Improving the speed of the code Base significantly helped though.